# Changing variables

Tags: c#, optimization

I am sure this is just something simple but I am just getting into C# and this isn't clicking in my mind.

I basically need to assign to a button of mine the function of changing the variable `offsets` that my tool uses to write data to my 3DS.

I have both variables but I don't really know how to tell it to switch from using `1` set to the other when I press it and then waterfall back if I press it again.

This is my code here showing my variables that are called upon throughout my tool

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

    public delegate void LogDelegate(string l);
    public LogDelegate delLastLog;
    public string lastlog = "";
    public int pid = 0;
    public PKHeX dumpedPKHeX = new PKHeX();
    //Possibly Ultra box layout Offset? 0x33015AB0
    //Possibly Ultra Wondercard Offset? 0x33075BF4
    public uint boxOff = 0x330D9838;
    public uint wcOff = 0x331397E4;
    public uint partyOff = 0x34195E10;
```

Then this is my button I have started.

```
private void btn_ConvertMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ultra Support Mode Activated!", "WonderInjection", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    return;
}
```

Any idea guys? Basically the `boxoff` and `wcoff` offsets I need to be able to be switched to the ones I have commented out one the command of the button.

Comment: are you trying to say you need something like a toggle button ? to simply change the values of the `boxoff` and `wcoff` variables

Comment: Yes! But i do not know how to write that up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just create a variable of type bool to hold the toggle state. On each button click event, toggle the state of this variable:

```
toggleVar = !toggleVar;
```

Then use the value of this toggleVar to decide which offset to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool isDefaultOffset(uint boxOff,uint wcOff)
{
    if((boxOff==0x330D9838))&&(wcOff==0x331397E4))
     return true;
    else 
     return false;
}

    public void ChangeOffSet(uint boxOff,uint wcOff)
{   
if(isDefaultOffset(boxOff,wcOff))
   {
      boxOff= 0x33015AB0;
      boxOff= 0x33075BF4;
   }
   else 
  {
    // set default values here 
  }

}
```

and then call changeOffset() method on your event.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two queues that would store the possible data and just dequeue and enqueue them, that would work exactly like a toggle button if there are only two values in a queue.

I would declare the queues in a class like this

```
Queue<string> qbox;
Queue<string> qwc;
```

Then I would initiate the queues like this in constructor or some other method.

```
qbox = new Queue<string>
{
    "0x330D9838", "0x33015AB0"
};
qwc = new Queue<string>
{
    "0x331397E4", "0x33075BF4"
};
```

then i would use them like this:

```
private void btn_ConvertMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    qbox.Enqueue(box);
    box = qbox.Dequeue();

    qwc.Enqueue(wc); //puts wc value to the back of the queue
    wc= qbox.Dequeue(); //removes first value from a queue and puts it in wc variable
}
```

qbox would add box value to the end of a queue and box would get the value from the start of a queue. Dequeued objects get removed from the queue.
Same for wc. I think this approach is very readable and managable because you dont have to deal with multiple if...thens. You just toggle between values.

You have to remember that box and wc variables also need to be initialised with some initial value.

Comment: Okay so then if i used queues do i need to declare my uint values again but as qbox and qwc in my main form instead of having them as boxOff and wcOff?

Comment: Also i cannot convert uint to string.